# How to reduce dex files in APK

Tags: android, apk, android-multidex

How to reduce dex files to minimal in my project?

It has more than 20 dex files

[image]

Some files only have 1 class, 1 method.

[image]

============

Update: For more info, this is my problem about debug apk

[image: Crash log]

============

Update 2: I don't use Instant Run in my project.

[image: Disable Instant Run]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you please post your build gradle

Comment: Here's a my build gradle [paste.ofcode.org][1]. Thanks

  [1]: paste.ofcode.org/TYmPdXV9Cik9dXMZ5x464q

Comment: you are analyzing debug APK?

Comment: Yes. I have a problem about debug apk. It's always crash with LinkageError in java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass. But release apk (with 3-4 dex files) run normal. So, I'd like try reduce dex files to resolve this issue.

Comment: @LongThanh Are you using Instant Run? Try without instant run. If you want to reduce the size then use flavour with different apk for different architecture Phones.

Comment: @AvinashVerma Thank you, but I don't want to reduce my apk size, it's only 40MB in debug mode. And I'm always disable Instant Run mode in Android Studio, I will add this info into my question.

Comment: proguard/obfuscation/something similar?